# How I can get the data with openDHT in C++?

Tags: c++, dht

This is the code. I put some "dummy" value with the key. And then I cannot print that value to screen. Last lines copied from main git website of openDHT. It does not work.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
#include <opendht.h>
#include <opendht/dht.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    dht::DhtRunner node;
    node.run(4222, dht::crypto::generateIdentity(), true);
    node.bootstrap("localhost", "4222");

    std::string buffer;
    bool running=true;

    while(running)
    {
        std::cout<<"Was?a oder q";
        buffer.clear();
        std::cin>>buffer;

        switch(buffer.c_str()[0])
        {
        case 'a':
        case 'A':
            std::cout<<"give Key: ";
            buffer.clear();
            std::cin>>buffer;
            node.put(dht::InfoHash::get(buffer.c_str()), "dummy");
            break;
        case 'q':
        case 'Q':
            running = false;
            break;
        default:
            std::cout<<"!!!Unknown Option!!!"<<std::endl;

        }
    }



      std::cout<<"give Key to get your value: ";
            buffer.clear();
            std::cin>>buffer;
            node.get(buffer.c_str(), [](const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<dht::Value>>& values)
            {
                // Callback called when values are found
                for (const auto& value : values)
                std::cout << "Found value: " << *value << std::endl;
                return true; // return false to stop the search
            });
    node.join();
    return 0;

}
```